# How to upload an image from a mongodb database with Symfony2 and SonataAdmin?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I don't know for sure if this question is fit to be here, but now that is my last option.

I am working in a symfony2 project, with a sonata admin and a mongodb database. We use Vich bundle to upload image to a amazon server.

I have two images, one is working normally, and the other not for some unknown reason.

When I try to add an image in the Sonata admin it simply doesn't update the photo, or simply keep in blank.

Here is the code of the one that is working normally.

**@my document**

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @MongoDB\String
 * @Serializer\Since("2.0")
 */
protected $image_button;


/**
   * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="folder_images", fileNameProperty="image_button")
   * @var File $image_button_file
   */
protected $image_button_file;


//GETTERS AND SETTERS

/**
 * Set imageButton
 *
 * @param string $imageButton
 * @return self
 */
public function setImageButton($imageButton)
{
    $this->image_button = $imageButton;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get imageButton
 *
 * @return string $imageButton
 */
public function getImageButton()
{
    return $this->image_button;
}



public function setImageButtonFile($imageButtonFile)
{
    $this->image_button_file = $imageButtonFile;
    if ($imageButtonFile) {
        $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
    }
    return $this;
}


public function getImageButtonFile()
{
    return $this->image_button_file;
```

---

**@my admin**

```
->tab('images')
     ->with('OTHERS',['class' => 'col-md-6'])
     ->add('image_button_file', 'custom_image')
  ->end()
->end()
```

---

**BUT** the following code doesn't

**@my document**

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @MongoDB\String
 * @Serializer\Since("2.0")
 */
protected $image_wordpress_header;

/**
 * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="folder_images", fileNameProperty="image_wordpress_header")
 * @var File $image_wordpress_header_file
 */
protected $image_wordpress_header_file;


//GETTERS AND SETTERS

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getImageWordpressHeader()
{
    return $this->image_wordpress_header;
}

/**
 * @param string $image_wordpress_header
 */
public function setImageWordpressHeader($image_wordpress_header)
{
    $this->image_wordpress_header = $image_wordpress_header;
}

/**
 * @return File
 */
public function getImageWordpressHeaderFile()
{
    return $this->image_wordpress_header_file;
}

/**
 * @param File $image_wordpress_header_file
 */
public function setImageWordpressHeaderFile($image_wordpress_header_file)
{
    $this->image_wordpress_header_file = $image_wordpress_header_file;
```

### }

**@my admin**

```
->tab('images')
     ->with('OTHERS',['class' => 'col-md-6'])
     ->add('image_wordpress_header_file', 'custom_image')
  ->end()
->end()
```

There is any suggestion at least how could I debug that?

Comment: Did you check the Symfony or Apache|Nginx logs? that would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I should update the document when changing the image. Otherwise it would not  update the database. I don't know why this happened with one and didn't happen with the another variable.

```
public function setImage2lFile($image2lFile)
     {
        $this->image2l_file = $image2lFile;
        if ($image2lFile) {
            $this->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```